# How to optimize BETWEEN condition on big table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a big table (about ten million rows) and I need to perform query with `? BETWEEN columnA AND columnB`.

Script to create database with table and sample data:

```
CREATE DATABASE test;
\c test
-- Create test table
CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY, range_start NUMERIC(12, 0), range_end NUMERIC(12, 0));
-- Fill the table with sample data
INSERT INTO test (SELECT value, value, value FROM (SELECT generate_series(1, 10000000) AS value) source);
-- Query I want to be optimized
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 5000000 BETWEEN range_start AND range_end;
```

I want to create INDEX so that PostgreSQL can do fast *INDEX SCAN* instead of *SEQ SCAN*. However I failed with my initial (and obvious) attempts:

```
CREATE INDEX test1 ON test (range_start, range_end);
CREATE INDEX test2 ON test (range_start DESC, range_end);
CREATE INDEX test3 ON test (range_end, range_start);
```

Also note that the number in the query is specifically chosen to be in the middle of generated values (otherwise PostgreSQL is able to recognize that the value is near range boundary and perform some optimizations).

Any ideas or thoughts would be appreciated.

---

**UPDATE 1** Based on the [official documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-multicolumn.html) it seems that PostgreSQL is not able to properly use indexes for multicolumn inequality conditions. I am not sure why there is such limitation and if there is anything I can do to significantly speed up the query.

---

**UPDATE 2** One possible approach would be to limit the INDEX SCAN by knowing what is the largest range I have, lets say it is 100000:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE range_start BETWEEN 4900000 AND 5000000 AND range_end > 5000000;
```

Comment: I didn't find a solution. Can I suggest write to postgresql specific ml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a second thought it is quite obvious why PostgreSQL can not use multicolumn index for two-column inequality condition. However what I did not understand was why there is SEQ SCAN even with LIMIT clause (sorry for not expressing that in my question):

```
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE 5000000 BETWEEN range_start AND range_end LIMIT 1;
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..0.09 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=4743.035..4743.037 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..213685.51 rows=2499795 width=16) (actual time=4743.032..4743.032 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: ((5000000::numeric >= range_start) AND (5000000::numeric <= range_end))
 Total runtime: 4743.064 ms
```

Then it hit me that PostgreSQL can not know that it is less probable that the result will be in `range_start=1` than `range_start=4999999`. That is why it starts scanning from the first row until it finds matching row(s).

The solution might be to convince PostgreSQL that there is some benefit to using the index:

```
test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM test WHERE 5000000 BETWEEN range_start AND range_end ORDER BY range_start DESC LIMIT 1;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.00..1.53 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.102..0.103 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan Backward using test1 on test  (cost=0.00..3667714.71 rows=2403325 width=16) (actual time=0.099..0.099 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ((5000000::numeric >= range_start) AND (5000000::numeric <= range_end))
 Total runtime: 0.125 ms
```

Quite a performance boost I would say :). However still, this boost will only work if such range exists. Otherwise it will be as slow as SEQ SCAN. So it might be good to combine this approach with what I have outlined in my second update to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try a range with a gist index ?

```
alter table test add  numr numrange;

update test set numr = numrange(range_start,range_end,'[]');

CREATE INDEX test_idx ON test USING gist (numr);

EXPLAIN ANALYZE  SELECT * FROM test WHERE 5000000.0  <@ numr;

Bitmap Heap Scan on public.test  (cost=2367.92..130112.36 rows=50000 width=48) (actual time=0.150..0.151 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: id, range_start, range_end, numr
  Recheck Cond: (5000000.0 <@ test.numr)
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_idx  (cost=0.00..2355.42 rows=50000 width=0) (actual time=0.142..0.142 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (5000000.0 <@ test.numr)
Total runtime: 0.189 ms
```

Comment: I am not familiar with GiST indexes... the query plan looks very interesting. Unfortunately I need to be able to run the query from Java+Hibernate (i.e. HQL), so that might be an issue for me. But I will check it.

Comment: Also seems that range types are only [available since](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/rangetypes.html) `9.2`.